# Select all from table with Laravel and Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using Laravel 4 to set up my first model to pull all the rows from a table called `posts`.

In standard MySQL I would use:

```
SELECT * FROM posts;
```

How do I achieve this in my Laravel 4 model?

See below for my complete model source code:

```
<?php

class Blog extends Eloquent 
{

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function getAllPosts()
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You simply call

```
Blog::all();

//example usage.
$posts = Blog::all();

$posts->each(function($post) // foreach($posts as $post) { }
{
    //do something
}
```

from anywhere in your application.

Reading the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs) will help a lot.

Comment: Be careful using `::all()` as it reads _everything_ from the table into memory. If you table has many records, you can quickly exceed PHP's memory limit that way. The solution is apparently to use `Builder::cursor()` or `Builder::chunk()`.

Comment: You will get 500 error message with this `Blog::all();` if you reach maximum memory limit with apache

Comment: Slight update to the code there: you need closing brackets and semicolon so: 
    $posts->each(function($post)
        {
            //do something
        });

Comment: any comments on how to check if the $posts is empty.

Answer (score 50):

There are 3 ways that one can do that.

### 1 - Use all() or get();

```
$entireTable = TableModelName::all();
```

eg,

```
$posts = Post::get(); // both get and all  will work here
```

or

```
$posts = Post::all();
```

### 2 - Use the DB facade

Put this line before the class in the controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; // this will import the DB facade into your controller class
```

Now in the class

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')->get(); // it will get the entire table
```

or a more dynamic way would be -

```
$postTable = (new Post())->getTable(); // This will get the table name
$posts = DB::table($postTable)->get();
```

The advantage of this way is that in case you ever change the table name, it would not return any error since it gets the table name dynamically from the `Post` model. Make sure to import `Post` model at the top like `DB` fadade.

### 3 - Use the DB facade with select

Put this line before the class in the controller

```
*Same import the DB facade like method 2*
```

Now in the controller

```
$posts = DB::select('SELECT * FROM posts');
```

Answer (score 10):

go to your Controller write this in function

```
public function index()
{
  $posts = \App\Post::all();

  return view('yourview', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

in view to show it

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
  {{ $post->yourColumnName }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, to do it with eloquent you would do:

```
Blog:all();
```

From within your Model you do:

```
return DB::table('posts')->get();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/queries

Comment: Why not just $this->all()? That seems really roundabout.

Answer (score 4):

> How to get all data from database to view using laravel, i hope this solution would be helpful for the beginners.

Inside your controller

```
public function get(){
        $types = select::all();
        return view('selectview')->with('types', $types);}
```

Import data model inside your controller, in my application the data model named as select.

```
use App\Select;
```

Inclusive of both my controller looks something like this

```
use App\Select;
class SelectController extends Controller{                             
    public function get(){
    $types = select::all();
    return view('selectview')->with('types', $types);}
```

select model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Select extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email','phone','radio1','service',
    ];


    protected $table = 'selectdata';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

inside router

```
Route::get('/selectview', 'SelectController@get');
```

selectview.blade.php

```
@foreach($types as $type)
    <ul>
    <li>{{ $type->name }}</li>
    </ul>

    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Query
// Select all data of model table
Model::all();
// Select all data of model table
Model::get();

Model::where('foo', '=', 'bar')->get();

Model::find(1);
Model::find([1, 2, 3]);
Model::findOrFail(1);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code-only answers are improved by including an explanation of how you’ve answer addresses the question.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
$posts = Blog::get()->all();
```

Comment: This works. The get() method returns a Laravel Collection, then uses the all() method to return an array of results
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-all

Answer (score 1):

```
 public function getAllPosts()
 {
   return  Blog::all();        
 }
```

Have a look at the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) this is probably the first thing they explain..

Answer (score 1):

using [DB facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries) you can perform SQL queries

```
 public function index()
{
    return DB::table('table_name')->get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel Eloquent you can give the below queries in your controller to get all the data from your desired table:

```
$posts = Post::all();
return view('post', compact('posts'));
```

Or

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('id')->get();
return view('post', compact('posts'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$posts = DB::select('SELECT * FROM table_x');
```

or to get specific columns:

```
$posts = DB::select('SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c FROM table_x');
```

Comment: This goes against the MVC approach that Laravel takes. It will work but i think this is bad practice

Comment: Thanks Morris, please feel free to enhance the method

Comment: Well it's simple. Instead of making queries inside of your controller just call your model and let it execute database commands for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is very big, you can also process rows by "small packages" (not all at oce) (laravel doc: [Eloquent> Chunking Results](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) )

```
Post::chunk(200, function($posts)
{
    foreach ($posts as $post)
    {
        // process post here.
    }
});
```

Comment: @Kamlesh write you comment as separate question on stack overflow - with more details

Answer (score -1):

```
// Assuming your Post model is in the App\Models namespace
use App\Models\Post;

// Retrieve all posts
$posts= Post::all();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
   echo $post->your_column_name;
   ....
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: This is fundamentally just a copy of the accepted answer